# Start Windows automatically unless a key is pressed, then start Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows

I want to disable the boot menu and still be able to start Ubuntu instead of Windows by holding a key down.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify what you mean by "with a key". thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Done. I have edited

Comment: Could you not just set the time to like 2 seconds for the boot option menu and if no thing is pressed it starts windows as first choice?

Comment: I'm not the only who use this PC, because of this I want to start ubuntu manually and not with a start menu.

Comment: This is unnecessary. Other people without an Ubuntu account will be unable to log in anyway provided you apply basic security concepts regarding your password.

Comment: Is that possible or not? I'm here to solve my problem.

Comment: Are you trying to use the boot menu as some sort of security method? If someone has physical access to your machine, all bets are off. It doesn't matter if the person with physical access has an account or not, they could boot into the Ubuntu recovery menu and change your password, they could boot into a USB stick and change your password, etc. They could go into Kon-Boot and log into your account without even changing your password and you'd have no idea they did.

Please consider whether this is actually necessary as a security measure.

Answer (score 4):

For your needs you have to edit the GRUB configuration:

/etc/default/grub from Terminal using sudo

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

A fresh installation should look like this:

```
# This file is sourced by update-grub, and its variables are propagated
# to its children in /etc/grub.d/
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT="3"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entrys
## Bis GRUB 1.98
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_RECOVERY="true"
## Ab GRUB 1.99
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

To automatically boot Windows, you have to change

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
```

to the number of the entry for Windows in GRUB. Keep in mind that the menu entries start at 0, not 1.

To disable the menu, you have to enable

```
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
```

by removing the '#' and changing the value from '0' to '1' like this: `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=1`.

You also have to disable

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT="3"
```

by placing a '#' at the beginning of the line like this: `#GRUB_TIMEOUT="3"`

When you are done editing, save the file and then run the following command to apply the changes:

```
sudo update-grub
```

If you then want to boot into Ubuntu (or any other OS) you have to hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>⇧</kbd> while starting, then the GRUB-Menu will be displayed and you can select Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure **grub2** to do exactly what you want. You can configure **grub2** by editing `/etc/default/grub` when running **Ubuntu**.

```
sudo  -i gedit /etc/default/grub
```

It will ask you for your password. This means that your system is trying to protect you from yourself. Make sure you know what you're doing. Don't take my word for it. Read [the documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup#Configuring_GRUB_2). If you are at all unclear as to what you're doing, it's wise to create a backup with the default settings in tact (`sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.old`) before editing the file.

Once you enter your password, **gedit** should open. Below is what I see when it opens up. You'll see something slightly different than this, as I don't dual boot:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

What you want is (1) make **grub** boot **Windows 7** by default and (2) make the **grub** menu invisible unless you press a key. (1) can be achieved by changing the value of `DEFAULT_GRUB=` and (2) can be achieved by changing the value of `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=`.

1. There are several ways to go about this. You can set `DEFAULT_GRUB=#`, where `#` is the entry number of **Windows 7** in the **grub** menu. The entries start at `0`, so if **Windows 7** is the third menu option, you would set `DEFAULT_GRUB=2`. You can also set `DEFAULT_GRUB="xxxx"`, where `"xxxx"` is the name of your Windows 7 install as it appears in the grub menu. Make sure to include the quotation marks (") if you choose the latter option.

Save the file and exit gedit.

2. You're going to want to uncomment the `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` and comment out the `GRUB_TIMEOUT` line. We also need to set the hidden timeout value to 1.

Run the following command to make the changes:

```
sudo sed -i 's/^\#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT/GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT/g;s/^GRUB_TIMEOUT/#GRUB_TIMEOUT/g;s/^GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=.*$/GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=1/g'
```

Finally, run the following command to apply the changes to grub and you'll be all set:

```
sudo update-grub
```

When you reboot your computer, it should boot **Windows 7** without showing the **grub** menu. Simply press the <kbd>shift</kbd> key during the boot process and the **grub** menu will appear.

Comment: how `shift`? is that the default? pressing shift breaks the timeout?

Comment: @SaravanabalagiRamachandran Shift will work if you set the hidden timeout to 1 and comment out the GRUB_TIMEOUT line.